# Migrating row from one table to another with conditions [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 MYSQL TABLES:

```
TABLE 1:

PRODUCTID | BRAND | BASECOLOR | COLORNAME

Table 2:

PRODUCTID | BRAND | COLORNAME
```

In table 1 the field 'COLORNAME' is empty and the fields 'PRODUCTID' and 'BRAND' must match in the two tables. I need to moove the row 'COLORNAME' from table2 to table 1. I've done this SQL request:

```
INSERT INTO tablel (COLORNAME) SELECT COLORNAME FROM table2 WHERE table1.PRODUCTID = table2.PRODUCTID AND table1.BRAND  = table2.BRAND
```

I've been given this answer:

*Unknown column 'table1.PRODUCTID' in 'where clause'*

I'm new in SQL so I'm a bit lost, I would thank some help.

Comment: What are you want to do is an update if i understand you correct.

Comment: yes, but my conflict happens when I do the comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
update table1 tab1, table2 tab2 set tab1.colorname=tab2.colorname where tab2.brand=tab1.brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tablel (COLORNAME) (SELECT t2.COLORNAME FROM table2 t2,tablel t1 WHERE t1.PRODUCTID = t2.PRODUCTID AND t1.BRAND  = t2.BRAND)
```

Comment: This request added the row, but I need that the values of 'COLORNAME' matches with their 'PRODUCTID' and 'BRAND', so I think I need an 'update'. I'm afraid I didn't explain myself quite well.

Comment: As I understand, t1.PRODUCTID = t2.PRODUCTID AND t1.BRAND  = t2.BRAND  this portion is solving your problem.

Comment: If this is not solving your problem, please give some sample data and explain the problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need UPDATE JOIN tables not INSERT:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 a 
    JOIN TABLE2 b ON a.PRODUCTID=b.PRODUCTID AND a.BRAND=b.BRAND
SET a.COLORNAME = b.COLORNAME
```