# MySQL UPDATE script not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run an UPDATE script across two tables, but it isn't working.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong:

```
UPDATE adb_addressbook a, a_table b
SET a.gtxr2_product_family = b.product_family,
SET a.gtxr2_product_family_factory = b.factory,  
SET a.gtxr2_product_family_model = b.model,
SET a.gtxr2_product_family_size = b.size
WHERE a.contact_id = b.contact_id;
```

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824017/migrating-row-from-one-table-to-another-with-conditions-mysql/23824617#23824617) seems that is an equals problem.

Comment: what is the error it showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be

```
update adb_addressbook a
JOIN a_table b on b.contact_id = a.contact_id
SET a.gtxr2_product_family = b.product_family,
 a.gtxr2_product_family_factory = b.factory,  
 a.gtxr2_product_family_model = b.model,
 a.gtxr2_product_family_size = b.size;
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c68e1/1)**

Comment: Thank you everyone (I've been spending a bit too much time on the computer this weekend - everything seems a little foggy).  I really appreciate the help (yet again).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.. It should be something like that

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.NAME = B.NAME
FROM TableNameA A, TableNameB B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```